# How can I merge 2 partition with data in one of them?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, gparted

I am trying to use Gparted to extend the partition `/dev/sdb5` which I used 47/50 GiB. I have a new empty partition `/dev/sdb6` with 200 GiB capacity. I tried to resize/move but this not works.

How can I merge these two partitions into one?

Edit: How can I move entire my data from `/dev/sdb5` to `/dev/sdb6` in case there is no way to merge 2 partitions?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the empty partition (/dev/sbd6), resulting in unallocated space of 200 GiB, and then add this unallocated space to partition dev/sbd5? Disclaimer: I have not tried myself whether this would work.

Comment: I tried it already. Gparted just allows me to create a new partition with unallocated space.

Comment: Is /dev/sdb5 mounted ? You can't change a mounted partition - if the partition is mounted, there are a little lock symbol at it in gparted. Unmount it if possible, or boot from live media (USB or DVD) and then change the partition size in gparted.

Comment: @SorenA Yes, /dev/sdb5 mounted to / directory so I cannot unmount it. I have an error: umount / target is busy

Comment: @ThanhKiet then read the next part of my comment; boot from Live media ...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to merge the two partitions is as follows:

1. Boot the system via a Live USB;
2. Load up Gparted
3. Check whether the said partition /dev/sdb6 (with 200 GiB capacity) is listed as free, unallocated space; if not, delete it. It will show as unallocated space.
4. Unmount partition /dev/sdb5, if mounted.
5. Resize partition /dev/sdb5 to the capacity you want.

Wait until completed. It should work.

Comment: I also tried booting via Live USB. In this way,  the partition /dev/sdb5 which I need to extend is unmounted but I still can not resize it.